# If construct for multiple expressions

Tags: php

I'm working on something like this:

```
if ($varA != null & $varB = null){
     $newthing = "Something else";
}
```

It doesn't seem to want to work.  I've tried `&&` for `&` but I can find a good reference for these and what they do.

**EDIT:** Going to try and clear up what my objective is.

I have three `if` statement that I want to execute whether or not some variables have value in an encoded URL.  Those three statement are:

```
    if ($lprice != null && $hprice == null){
        $clauses[] = "MSTLISTPRC  >= " . $lprice;
    }
    if ($hprice != null && $lprice == null)(
        $clauses[] = "MSTLISTPRC  <= " . $hprice;
    } 
    if ($lprice != null && $hprice != null){
        $clauses[] = "MSTLISTPRC BETWEEN " . $lprice . " AND " . $hprice;
    }
```

The final `if` statement works, the first two don't.  It's something with the PHP code itself because I'm testing it an `echo` to just output the query string and when I try to execute this, it fails.  I don't know how to apply error handling so I haven't been using that.

Comment: If the final one is called, it's because neither $lprice or $hprice are null, so the other two if statements could not be called because they each require one of them to be null... I'm still confused.

Comment: It's not a matter of them being called or not, it's a matter of nothing being displayed on the page.  When I comment out the first two lines, the script displays a result.  When I include them, I get a blank screen.  Like there's a syntax error or something.  Like [this](http://www.mgoode.com/index.php?option=com_mls&view=list).

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting, to make sure it reports errors that would normally slip through?

Comment: I don't know anything about error reporting.

Comment: Insert error_reporting(E_ALL) at the top of your code, re-run and see if it tells you anything.

Comment: did that, didn't work.  On a hunch, I commented them all out and then started including them one by one.  The second state seems to be the problem.  It must be a typo somewhere.

Comment: Second `if` statement.  After the conditional command starts with `(` instead of `{`.  :P

Comment: Your second if statement has a parenthesis ( instead of a brace {

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use && instead of & and == instead of =.

So:

```
if ($varA != null && $varB == null){
     $newthing = "Something else";
}
```

Comment: @Plummer: if it's still not working, check the values of $varA, $varB and verify the if statement is being reached.  If that's still not helping out, try posting some more relevant code to show context.

Comment: The $varA and $varB are being reached.  I something equivalent to a `BUT` statement.  Where `if( $a != null BUT $b == null){ $doSomething }`.  I need a BUT operator. :/

Comment: Could you give every possible combination of a & b and the desired result? That will make the desired boolean operator clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($varA != null && $varB = null){
 $newthing = "Something else";
}
```

this should be fine..